# How to store data offline and then upload later in the firebase when app has internet access?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm creating an app which takes inputs from the user and upload in the firebase. The app works fine if the app has internet access. But I want to make my app to take inputs and store these data offline if app do not have internet access and then upload in the firebase when app get internet access.

I also use '**Disk Persistence**'

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

And '**Keeping Data Fresh**'

```
DatabaseReference scoresRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("scores");
scoresRef.keepSynced(true);
```

But this isn't working for me. Maybe I not using it correctly.

My code is

**AddDataActivity**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    binding = ActivityAddDataBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(binding.getRoot());
    Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Add Data");
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    database.getReference().child("Users").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid()).child("data_added_by_user").keepSynced(true);
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(AddDataActivity.this);
    progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    progressDialog.setTitle("Adding Data");
    progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait ...");
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

    Intent mintent = getIntent();
    String activity = mintent.getStringExtra("activity");
    if (activity.equals("list")){
        String date = mintent.getStringExtra("date");
        String name = mintent.getStringExtra("name");
        String weight = mintent.getStringExtra("weight");
        String rate = mintent.getStringExtra("rate");
        binding.editDate.setText(date);
        binding.editName.setText(name);
        binding.editWeight.setText(weight);
        binding.editRate.setText(rate);
    }





    binding.btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (binding.editDate.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(AddDataActivity.this, "Enter Date", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (binding.editName.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(AddDataActivity.this, "Enter Name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else if (binding.editWeight.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(AddDataActivity.this, "Enter Weight", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {
                if (notValidDateFormat(binding.editDate.getText().toString(), "yyyy-MM-dd")
                        || notValidDateFormat(binding.editDate.getText().toString(), "yyyy/MM/dd")
                        || notValidDateFormat(binding.editDate.getText().toString(), "yyyy.MM.dd")){

                    progressDialog.show();
                    DataModel data = new DataModel();
                    int weight = Integer.parseInt(binding.editWeight.getText().toString());
                    int rate = Integer.parseInt(binding.editRate.getText().toString());
                    data.setDate(binding.editDate.getText().toString());
                    data.setName(binding.editName.getText().toString());
                    data.setWeight(weight);
                    data.setRate(rate);
                    data.setAddedBy(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid());
                    if (!activity.equals("list")) {
                        data.setAddedTime(new Date().getTime());
                        data.setSell(true);
                        String dataId = database.getReference().child("Users").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid()).child("data_added_by_user").push().getKey();
                        data.setDataId(dataId);
                        database.getReference().child("Users").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid()).child("data_added_by_user").child(dataId).setValue(data)
                                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(Void unused) {
                                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                                        Toast.makeText(AddDataActivity.this, "Data Added!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        Intent intent = new Intent(AddDataActivity.this, ItemListActivity.class);
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                        finish();
                                    }
                                });
                    } else{
                        database.getReference().child("Users").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid()).child("data_added_by_user").child(mintent.getStringExtra("id")).child("modifiedTime").setValue(new Date().getTime());
                        database.getReference().child("Users").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid()).child("data_added_by_user").child(mintent.getStringExtra("id")).child("date").setValue(binding.editDate.getText().toString());
                        database.getReference().child("Users").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid()).child("data_added_by_user").child(mintent.getStringExtra("id")).child("name").setValue(binding.editName.getText().toString());
                        database.getReference().child("Users").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid()).child("data_added_by_user").child(mintent.getStringExtra("id")).child("weight").setValue(weight);
                        database.getReference().child("Users").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid()).child("data_added_by_user").child(mintent.getStringExtra("id")).child("rate").setValue(rate)
                                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(Void unused) {
                                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                                        Toast.makeText(AddDataActivity.this, "Data Modified!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        Intent intent = new Intent(AddDataActivity.this, ItemListActivity.class);
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                        finish();
                                    }
                                });
                    }

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(AddDataActivity.this, "Invalid Date Format! ", 
       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }

    });


}
```

For **Disk Persistence**,I create new java class named same as project name

```
public class PhoNote extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
  }
}
```

**Thanks!!**

Comment: "But this isn't working for me." doesn't provide enough information so we can help.  What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: @AlexMamo This code works fine if the app gets internet access. The problem is not with this code. I just want to implement offline feature as well in my app. How to implement?

Comment: @Regmi That leaves the same question: **what** isn't working about the code you shared?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen When app do not have Internet access, if I press btnSubmit it show progressdialog but never dismiss.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase doesn't treat the lack of an internet connection as an error condition when writing to the database. Instead, it keeps the data in memory in that situation (and also on disk if you [enabled disk persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-disk-persistence)) and synchronizes it to the server when the connection is reestablished.

When you attach a completion listener or a success listener to the write operation, that only fires once the operation is committed or rejected on the server. There are cases where this may be important, but in most cases you actually don't need

This means that in most cases you don't need a completion listener, or even a progress dialog, on write operation to Firebase. Instead you should treat them as if they're local, instantaneous and are completed by the time the `setValue()` call has executed.

So:

```
database.getReference().child("Users").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid()).child("data_added_by_user").child(dataId).setValue(data);

Toast.makeText(AddDataActivity.this, "Data Added!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
Intent intent = new Intent(AddDataActivity.this, ItemListActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Comment: This solve the progress dialog dismiss problem BUT do not synchronizes entered data to the server when the connection is reestablished.

Comment: The pending writes should be synchronized automatically once the connection is reestablished. Is that not happening for you?

Comment: YES, That's not happening. If you want complete project [Here](https://github.com/prabesh-regmi/PhoNote) is the github link

Comment: Instead, can you [enable debug logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase.html#setLogLevel(com.google.firebase.database.Logger.Level)) and check if the logcat shows Firebase reconnecting to the database in that scenario?

Comment: I finally made it. Thanks a lot.